# Get all the values in the table if parameter is null

Tags: php, laravel

```
Products::active($userId) ->where('name','like','%'.Input::get('search').'%') ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') ->with('color') ->whereHas('seasons', function ($query)use($seasons) { $query->whereIn('season_id', $seasons); });
```

In the above query I want to get all the results if `$seasons` is null. In sql we can write where(`$seasons` is null) or (`season_id` in `$season`). How can I write this in laravel. Also whereHas makes an inner join. So products that have atleast one season will come. How can I make it a left join so that all products will come if season is null?

Comment: Any reasons to not using this? `if($seasons !== null) $query->whereIn('season_id', $seasons); //else it will ignore and get all` Also you can use query builder

Comment: @GONG          It won't work because whereHas makes an inner join. Also I want to add one more whereHas for another condition. So I am trying to avoid using php conditions.

Comment: do a `->where()` and nest the `whereHas` within the where. That way you can check if seasons is null or not.

Comment: I think adding `$query->whereNull('season_id')` should do the trick.

Comment: @GONG          Sorry. As I said earlier it won't work because whereHas makes an inner join. How can I make al left join.